# Laravel how to addSelect all total counts on a single table each row

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

i am trying to build a single query but something is wrong. i want to write a code that each row have a all total count on a one table. i will describe

first i will query the total counts :

```
$count = Rating::whereIN('book_id',Books::select('id'))->count();

//the all total counts of this ratings table is 12
```

second is querying the books count each rows in ratings with authors :

```
 return  $books = Books::withCount('rating')
        ->with(['author:id,user_id','author.user:id,name,email'])
        ->get();
```

the output of this :

```
[
  {
  "id": 1,
  "created_at": "2022-06-15T09:59:10.000000Z",
  "updated_at": "2022-06-15T09:59:10.000000Z",
  "author_id": 2,
  "title": "vel",
  "name": "Qui odit eum ea recusandae rem officiis.",
  "rating_count": 5,
  "author": {
          "id": 2,
          "user_id": 1,
          "user": {
                  "id": 1,
                  "name": "Joshua Weber",
                  "email": "bhessel@example.com"
                }
          }
  },
  {
  "id": 2,
  "created_at": "2022-06-15T09:59:10.000000Z",
  "updated_at": "2022-06-15T09:59:10.000000Z",
  "author_id": 1,
  "title": "atque",
  "name": "Beatae tenetur modi rerum dolore facilis eos incidunt.",
  "rating_count": 7,
  "author": {
          "id": 1,
          "user_id": 5,
          "user": {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Miss Destinee Nitzsche III",
                "email": "jamir.powlowski@example.net"
          }
      }
  }
]
```

you can see in this code each row has own their **rating_count** in `id:1` has **rating_count** 5 and in `id:2` has rating count 7 when summing them total of 12.

now the point of my problem is i want to add **`addSelect()`** in the `Book::withCount` i want to add the **first query** i wrote. so each row has a total books of 12

i tried this code but it gives a error:

```
   return  $books = Books::withCount('rating')
        ->with(['author:id,user_id','author.user:id,name,email'])
        ->addSelect(['total_books'=>Rating::whereIN('book_id',Books::select('id'))->count()])
        ->get();
```

the error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '105' in 'field list' (SQL: select `books`.*, (select count(*) from `ratings` where `books`.`id` = `ratings`.`book_id`) as `rating_count`, `105` from `books`)
```

here is my tables: ( i did not add row created_at and updated_ad in authors and ratings )

```
my table authors

id    |   user_id   
1     |   1        
2     |   5          


my table books 

id    |  created_at | updated_at | author_id   |  title   |   name
1     |             |            |   1         |  vel     |   Qui odit eum ea recusandae rem officiis
2     |             |            |   2         |  atque   |   Beatae tenetur modi rerum dolore facilis eos incidunt.
 
my table ratings

id    |   rating   |  book_id   
1     |   5        |    1  
2     |   4        |    1  
3     |   4        |    1  
4     |   3        |    1  
5     |   2        |    1  
6     |   1        |    1  
7     |   1        |    1  
8     |   5        |    2  
9     |   4        |    2  
10    |   3        |    2  
11    |   3        |    2  
12    |   1        |    2
```

here is my models

model Authors

```
class Author extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function books(){
        return $this->hasMany(Books::class);
    }

    public function User(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

model Books

```
class Books extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function rating(){
        return $this->hasMany(Rating::class,'book_id');
    }

    public function author(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Author::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please first share examples of your tables to let us understand schema then share the result you want to achieve. In your code there are two independent query so 105 is the result of Rating::whereIn and the second one throws SQL Error cause 105 is not a column.

Comment: i already eddited, already added my tables and models.

Comment: You simple count total only one time, then reuse it for mapping to `$books`.
Sum all values without specify the scope means nothing, also it takes the query slow down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand the query for count of **total_books**

```php
$count = Rating::whereIN('book_id',Books::select('id'))->count();
```

The above query is essentially the count of records in the **ratings** table. Since the records in **ratings** table will have a valid value for **book_id** (assuming integrity constraints are defined) which means that for any row/record in the **ratings** table the value contained in **book_id** will be an **id** of an existing record in **books** table.

So the `whereIn('book_id', Book::select('id'))` is unnecessary. You can do just

```php
$count = Rating::count();

//Which will output the same result as
//$count = Rating::whereIN('book_id',Books::select('id'))->count();
```

Then you can have your composite query with **addSelect** as

```php
$books = Books::query()
  ->withCount('rating')
  ->with(['author:id,user_id','author.user:id,name,email'])
  ->addSelect([
    'total_books' => Rating::selectRaw('count(*)')
  ])
  ->get();
```

Or using **selectRaw**

```php
$books = Books::query()
    ->withCount('rating')
    ->with(['author:id,user_id','author.user:id,name,email'])
    ->selectRaw('? as total_ratings', [Rating::count()])
    ->get();
```

The **total_books** should probably be named as **total_ratings**

If you still want to have your **whereIn** constraint (which isn't necessary) you can

```php
$books = Books::query()
    ->withCount('rating')
    ->with(['author:id,user_id','author.user:id,name,email'])
    ->addSelect([
        'total_books' => Rating::selectRaw('count(id)')
            ->whereIn('book_id', Book::select('id'))
    ])
    ->get();
```

The above will generate an sql

```sql
select `books`.*, 
  (select count(*) from `ratings` where `books`.`id` = `ratings`.`book_id`) as `rating_count`, 
  (select count(id) from `ratings` where `book_id` in (select `id` from `books`)) as `total_books` 
from `books`
```

OR with **selectRaw**

```php
$books = Books::query()
    ->withCount('rating')
    ->with(['author:id,user_id','author.user:id,name,email'])
    ->selectRaw('? as total_ratings',[Rating::whereIn('book_id', Book::select('id'))->count()])
    ->get();
```

Comment: thank you so much for your explaining the `WhereIN`  i learned what was my mistake for this. and thank you for your answer and effort to teach and guide me  recorrecting my mistakes i made.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, you can count total ratings first, then reassign it to `$book` instance. Don't let SQL query calculates for every fetched rows if unnecessary.

```
$books = Books::query()
    ->with(['author:id,user_id','author.user:id,name,email'])
    ->get();

$count = Rating::query()
    ->whereIn('book_id', $books->pluck('id')->toArray())
    ->count();

foreach ($books as $book) {
    $book->rating_count = $count;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the guide and tip you give. i appreciated so much i will noted that.